# How do you write the following in proper notation?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I would like help in determining the proper notation to say:

> The a group $G$ acting on a set of 3 points formed by the quotients $G/H$ where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ is homomorphic to $S_3$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let G be a group isomorphic to $S_3$: $G \cong S_3$.

$H$ is a normal subgroup of G: $H \le G$

The group action: Define the map $f: G \rightarrow G/H$ by $g \mapsto gH$.

Comment: $\leq$ is standard notation for "is a subgroup of", not "is a normal subgroup of", which is usually denoted $\trianglelefteq$

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to put it this way:

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $H \subseteq G$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. (i.e.)Let $H \trianglelefteq G$ such that $|G/H|=3$. $G \circlearrowright G/H$

**Why does this capture all the information**?

Since, $H$ is a normal subgroup, $G/H$ is known to be a group and, we call it the quotient group. Ang given that $G$ acts on $G/H$ (i.e.) $G \circlearrowright G/H$, there is a canonical homomorphism, say $\varphi$ such that,

$$\varphi:G \to \operatorname{Sym}(G/H) \cong S_3$$

This conveys that $G$ is homomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: I don't like this (although it can be saved!) for the simple reason you aren't using proper sentences. Are you saying *if* $H\unlhd G$ *then* $|G/H|=3$? Obviously not...but only 'cause I know you don't mean that! You need to be more clear.

Comment: (Also, it is perhaps useful to point out that there is no standard notation for a group action. See this mathoverflow discussion, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64544/what-is-the-standard-notation-for-group-action.)

Comment: @user1729 I have never used a _then_. But, I'll be more explicit right away! And, for the notation on action, the OP never asked for a notation to use in papers or sth. I assume that he will use it for his notes.